# Why does Logan stab walls?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In the film [Logan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3315342/) (2017), there is a scene during which Professor Xavier is having a seizure which seems to make it hard for people around him to move.
During this scene, Logan tries to reach Xavier and when he arrives in the hallway of the hotel, he starts stabbing the walls with his claws out.

**Why does he do that?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Leverage. Xavier's seizures cause everyone to be paralyzed. Logan's healing factor allows him some movement, but **the closer he moves to Xavier the stronger the effect by Xavier is**. By stabbing the walls, he uses them to climb towards an increasingly difficult to reach Xavier. It provides a hand hold he can push against, like rock climbing or climbing a rope.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was strange, because he only starts doing so during the last 10 feet before he reaches the door but all the way upstairs we don't see him do it, and his shift in behavior wasn't clear. At some point his claws don't get in and out properly, so I wondered if he was trying to force them in and out to pull them out all the way by doing that but your answer is probably correct.

Comment: @MicroMachine Logan is more affected by Professor X's seizure the closer he gets, so it gets harder for him to move, to the point where he's not really capable of doing so without assistance. That's either because the effect is stronger closer to the source (which would make sense), Logan is becoming weaker the longer he's exposed to it (may also make sense), or both.